# AJAX QUERY HADOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

So If more than one record for same person exists I need to show them as a single record in result set and account_status_value => 'RFND' and 'ACTV' should show as the column in that single record with 'y' flag and their total services also should show in separate column .

```
person_id   First_nm  Last_nm           RFND  ACTV  RFND_SERVICE ACTV_SERVICE
000130       aaa   ssss.... 'Y'    'Y'   3004          8953
```

I tried pivot its not working it out.. any idea to achieve this?

Comment: fyi: it's considered very rude here to post images of text, even formatted text like your results. It also makes it harder for you to get help, because now we may have to retype that to create a dataset to use to test our solutions. That will deter some people from even reading further into the question. Management Studio has an option on the toolbar to present the results as text you copy/paste into Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that even if the person is the same, the account is different. Including that in the results and in the GROUP BY prevents the records from rolling up nice like you want. If you remove that from the results and the GROUP BY, things start to work better. You can then put those back into the results by using a `CASE` in combination with an aggregate function... just be aware that if there's more than one RFND or ACTV account, you can't be sure of what you end up with like this:

```
SELECT SVC.PERSON_ID, SVC.FIRST_NM, SVC.LAST_NM, 
    SUM(SVC.LEGACY_SVC_DAYS) As LEGACY_SVC_DAYS,
    SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_YEARS,0)) * 365 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_MONTHS,0)) * 30 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_DAYS,0)) AS TOTAL_SERVICE,
    CAST((SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_YEARS,0)) * 365 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_MONTHS,0)) * 30 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_DAYS,0))) AS INT) / 365 AS TOTAL_YEARS,
    (CAST((SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_YEARS,0)) * 365 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_MONTHS,0)) * 30 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_DAYS,0)))AS INT) % 365) / 30 AS TOTAL_MONTHS,
    ((SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_YEARS,0)) * 365 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_MONTHS,0)) * 30 + SUM(ISNULL(ACTUAL_SERVICE_DAYS,0))) % 365) % 30 AS TOTAL_DAYS,

    -------- New ---------
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN SPA.ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'RFND' THEN SPA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS RFND,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN SPA.ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'ACTV' THEN SPA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS ACTV
    MAX(CASE WHEN SPA.ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'RFND' THEN SPA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID ELSE 0 END) AS RFND_SERVICE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SPA.ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'ACTV' THEN SPA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID ELSE 0 END) AS ACTV_SERVICE

FROM RECON_CREDIT_SVC SVC
INNER JOIN PERSON_ACCOUNT SPA ON SPA.PERSON_ID = SVC.PERSON_ID
INNER JOIN  PA_SERVICE_SUMMARY_BKUP_10152016 PSS ON PSS.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = SPA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID

GROUP BY SVC.PERSON_ID, SVC.LEGACY_SVC_DAYS, SVC.FIRST_NM, SVC.LAST_NM
```

Comment: Here in  RFND_SERVICE It is showing person_account_id .We need service on this column.

Comment: I need to display TOTAL_MONTHS,TOTAL_YEARS,TOTAL_DAYS according to the status (RFND,ACTV)

Comment: I'm beginning to think you want to join to the PERSON_ACCOUNT table twice... one join pulls the RFND records, and the other pulls the ACTV records. Maybe even a third time for when you need sums of everything.